# How to keep the same Backbone template after reloading the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, handlebars.js

In my Backbone app (Rails backend), I am using [Handlebars] Javascript templates (JST's) for rendering my Backbone views.  Whenever I do a browser refresh while on one of those URL templates, it jumps back to the root URL.  I want it to stay on that current template after page-refresh.  I want to do something like this...

```
getPage: function() {
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var fragment = Backbone.history.fragment;
  });

  if (fragment === "this_current_template") {
    return App.getCurrentTemplatePage(); // render it
  } else if (fragment === "") {
    return App.getFrontMainPage(); // render it
  }
}
```

`getPage` is a method in my backbone `App` object.  My `fragment` variable can't be recognized outside of the `$(window)` event handler.  I can't seem to find a way to persist my previous `Backbone.history.fragment` in a variable, even if I make `fragment` global.  It's all swept away after refresh.  I know about `Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);`, but I just can't get that to work either.  It only seems to work prior to browser refresh.

Is it something I'll have to change in the `root` route of my backend code? or is there a way to persist the current page using Backbone / JS on page reload?  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd try Backbone.history.navigate(yourRoute)... which by default should change the browser url bar without reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I got it to work using `sessionStorage.setItem('fragment', fragment);` to retain the fragment after refresh.  Then I used a `Backbone.history.navigate(fragment);` to ensure I got to the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a Router. According to [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router):

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "main": "main"
  },
  main: function() {
    // your code here
  }
});
```

After that you only need to init [Backbone.history](http://backbonejs.org/#History):

```
Backbone.history.start({});
```

After that Backbone automatically will try to find appropriate route for your hashbang and fire the appropriate action. In given example if your initial hashbang will be `#main` then `Router.main` action will be executed.